# Javascript returns only keys but not values

Tags: javascript, json

The following is the data from the source file:

```
 {
 "dubbuseqchapter+block@a7a5931f68d0482eaff2b7c9f9684e47": {
    "category": "chapter", 
    "children": [
      "dubbuseqsequential+block@968513c8f0cc4249b7cfc2290ac967dc", 
      "dubbuseqsequential+block@f7f730a478144a74bd127f996d6dc4f5", 
      "dubbuseqsequential+block@91a0d5d7cd9649a3bdf057400e0a1c96", 
      "dubbuseqsequential+block@28b2b171b6734b13af29735796c5ad5a", 
      "dubbuseqsequential+block@192a150c8aab43b9bd236773ba60b414", 
      "dubbuseqsequential+block@26b3464dad42460ea66f9afe89770065"
    ], 
    "metadata": {
      "display_name": "Introduction course orientation"
    }
  }, 


  "dubbuseqchapter+block@b2451e9195c5466db8b66f53ed06c9fd": {
    "category": "chapter", 
    "children": [
      "dubbuseqsequential+block@c95826a16f71405ba58319d23d250fc4", 
      "dubbuseqsequential+block@fe4e3b8b7cdd4fa0b9fe9090223b7125", 
      "dubbuseqsequential+block@44bbdee625dc465ebe725d2126ed0662", 
      "dubbuseqsequential+block@8d4daba07d4443f3b2a0b2506280ee2c", 
      "dubbuseqsequential+block@c68d9d3ba7de45b1b0770085e4f1f286", 
      "dubbuseqsequential+block@ccdca5b2aca94dbdabb3a57a75adf3fa"
    ], 
    "metadata": {
      "display_name": "Module closing section"
    }
    }
    }
```

The following javascript brings the top key values (i.e dubbuseqchapter+block@a7a5931f68d0482eaff2b7c9f9684e47,dubbuseqchapter+block@b2451e9195c5466db8b66f53ed06c9fd )

Javascript code

```
    var obj = JSON.parse(jContent);
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);


    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var row = createRowCopy(getOutputRowMeta().size());
        var idx = getInputRowMeta().size();


            row[idx++] = keys[i];

        //  Alert (keys.length);

            putRow(row);
        }
```

However, I am unable to get the values of the keys..(i.e. Category, Children and metadata) in this example.

I have tried Objects.values() but it returns null or object object in the Alert.

Answer (score 5):

`keys` is an array of strings, each string being a property name.

You get the value for a property name in the usual way:

```
object[property_name]
```

i.e.

```
var value = obj[keys[i]];
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I really appreciate that. But all I got in the Alert box is Object Object...thats it...

Comment: @Dubbu — That's because it (the value) is an object and you've implicitly called `toString()` on it. What did you expect?

Comment: Hi Quentin, I dont know much about Javascript. I have picked up the code written by someone and managing to get things work. All I want is from the above json source is along with the Keys which it is populating, I need the values (Category, Children and Metadata). Would that be possible? Thanks

Comment: Those aren't values. Those are properties of the object (which is the value of the respective property of the parent object). You access them like any other property.

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse(jContent);
   var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    
  
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      var row = createRowCopy(getOutputRowMeta().size());
      var idx = getInputRowMeta().size();
   row[idx++] = keys[i];
   
     var value = obj[keys[i]];
       Alert (value);

    putRow(row);
   } Sorry, if I didnt understand...Thanks for your guidance...Still am getting Object Object as a value

Answer (score 0):

this code shows how to navigate into parsed JsonData

```
var obj = JSON.parse(textJson);
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(obj[keys[0]].metadata.display_name);
```

this will print : **Introduction course orientation**

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for your valuable tip. It works fine if I give Alert but I am unable to retrieve the Category, Children and Metada (all the 3 child elements). I am using the following code for the total output.    var obj = JSON.parse(jContent);
   var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    
  
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      var row = createRowCopy(getOutputRowMeta().size());
      var idx = getInputRowMeta().size();
   row[idx++] = keys[i];
   row[idx++] = obj[keys[i]].category;
  
    putRow(row);

    
    
   } I could bring upto category but not after that. Please help if poss.Thx

Answer (score 0):

Or even this way to retrieve your subProperties

```
var obj = JSON.parse(textJson);
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  console.log(keys[i]);
  var subKeys = Object.keys(obj[keys[i]]);
  for (var j = 0; j < subKeys.length; j++) console.log(subKeys[j] + " --> " + obj[keys[i]][subKeys[j]]);
}
```